# Using previous values of outcome variable as predictor

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series

Suppose you want to predict an outcome variable $Y$ using previous values of the variable as a predictor. For suppose $Y$ is the daily temperature in California and $X_1, \dots, X_3$ are the daily temperatures in Ohio, Delaware, and Florida. How would you use the previous values of $Y$ along with $X_1, \dots, X_3$ to predict $Y$?

Comment: To start you could run a linear regression using the Xs and lagged Ys to predict Y.

Comment: See DREGAR package in R and corresponding paper.

Comment: Adding the previous temperature in California as a predictor will improve the model predictions too!

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to look into Time Series models https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series